# Why is Geoseries.translate not working, even with the example given by geopandas?

Tags: geopandas

I'm using the example provided by Geoopandas, but can't get geoseries.translate to work

```
import os, geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

test = geopandas.GeoSeries(
    [
        Point(1, 1),
        LineString([(1, -1), (1, 0)]),
        Polygon([(3, -1), (4, 0), (3, 1)]),
    ]
)

test.translate(2, 3)

print(test)
```

the print statement produces:

0  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)

1  LINESTRING (1.00000 -1.00000, 1.00000 0.00000)

2  POLYGON ((3.00000 -1.00000, 4.00000 0.00000, 3...
dtype: geometry

**Any ideas how to fix this so I can use the translate function?**

Answer (score 1):

`translate` does not work in place but returns a new (translated) GeoSeries. You need to assign it to a new variable or replace the original one.

```py
import os, geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

test = geopandas.GeoSeries(
    [
        Point(1, 1),
        LineString([(1, -1), (1, 0)]),
        Polygon([(3, -1), (4, 0), (3, 1)]),
    ]
)

translated = test.translate(2, 3)

print(translated)
```

```
0                              POINT (3.00000 4.00000)
1        LINESTRING (3.00000 2.00000, 3.00000 3.00000)
2    POLYGON ((5.00000 2.00000, 6.00000 3.00000, 5....
dtype: geometry
```